# Class passar função

Tags: javascript, typescript, react, react-native

Preciso utilizar o mesmo botão em paginas diferentes e com funções diferentes

Como posso passar a função pro botão ?

```
class App extends Component {
   render(){
      return(
        <View>
           <Button title="Abrir conta" />
        </View>
      )
   }
}

const Button = (props) => (
   <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
         <Text>{props.title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
)
```

Comment: A sua pergunta está um pouco vaga. Poderia editá-la, adicionando um pouco mais de detalhes, por favor? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class App extends Component {
   render(){
      return(
        <View>
           <Button title="Abrir conta" onPress={()=> this._something()} />
        </View>
      )
   }
}

export default Button = (props) => (
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>
      <Text>{props.title}</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

Comment: edite seu codigo que eu te respondo

Comment: pronto editei amigo

Comment: Mesma coisa, nao muda nada